# Implementation of a Tensorflow 4D Convolutional Layer Transpose (aka 4D deconvolution)

Tags: tensorflow

I've been looking for an implementation of a 4D Conv layer in TensorFlow and found a solution here: https://github.com/funkey/conv4d

It seems that in the case of 4D convolutional layer, frame_results is the output and is the result of summing the convolution of the current input frame with its previous kernel frame:

```
frame_conv3d = tf.layers.conv3d(...)
if frame_results[out_frame] is None:
    frame_results[out_frame] = frame_conv3d
else:
    frame_results[out_frame] += frame_conv3d
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me with the transpose version of this 4D Conv layer also known as deconvolution. How would that look like in a TensorFlow implementation?

The reverse would be the result of summing the 3D transpose layers? Or is there more to it?

Comment: You should give any progression you have so far (code maybe?) and edit the title to be more precise :)

Comment: Thank you @PaulRey I tried to add more details and changed the title.